# Sine substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

My book says the following:

$$\int \frac{dx}{(16-x^2)^{3/2}}$$ 
$$x = 4\sin\theta$$
$$(16 - x^2)^{3/2} = (4^2\cos^2\theta)^{3/2}$$
$$=(4\cos\theta)^3$$

I don't understand the last step:

Doesn't:

$$(4^2\cos^2\theta)^{3/2} = (|4\cos\theta|)^3$$

Since:

$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

Comment: You are right, but $\theta$ is taken to be in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, since it is the arcsine of $\frac{x}{a}$, and therefore $\cos\theta\ge0$.

Comment: @user84413 Fair enough, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are really letting $\theta=\arcsin(x/4)$. So $\theta$ ranges over the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, and the cosine in this interval is non-negative.

Comment: You are welcome. The kind of issue you raised *does* come up in some definite integrals by substitution, and if not looked at carefully, can lead to error.